# Angular - attach directive to future element

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

First of all, I am ery new to Angular, so sorry if my question seems strange.

I know how to attach basic directives like `ng-click` to elements like that:

```
<button class="test" ng-click="clearOverlays()">Remove</button>
```

But how can I attach a directive to input box that will be dinamically generated by Django template language ? Django code:

```
<ul>{{ filter.form.as_ul }}</ul>
```

The future element will look like that:

```
<input id="id_property_parent" name="property_parent" type="radio" value="12">
```

So the ideal variant would be if I would be able to attach ng-change directive to a future element by it's ID ('id_property_parent')

Is it possible to do it with Angular js framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it depends on what you are really trying to achieve. I see two different cases, but from what I can tell, yours quite simple to solve. 
The two cases are :

- the dynamic piece of html generated by Django is loaded into the DOM via AJAX;
- the dynamic piece of html is inserted into the full document before the page is sent to the client.

Correct me if I am wrong but I think your case is the second. In that case, the only thing you have to do is to add an attribute (in your case `ng-change`) to your input. 
When Angular will parse the document, it will find and compile the `ng-change` directive without the need to add any other JS code.

So basically, the question you have to ask is more : "how to add custom attribute to Django's form inputs?"

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you :) I didnt even think about this approach and was thinking about some complicated Angular way. Adding an attribute to a field via Django was much easier.